# Quick search not working

Tags: quicksearch

At some point within the past few upgrades (currently on 4.7.11) our quick search stopped working (i.e. you type a name, but the search doesn't yield results as you type) and we've no idea why. How would we even start to troubleshoot and/or resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you checked settings at Administer -> Configuration Checklist -> Search Settings?

Comment: Do you see any ajax call made at the console ? Eg `civicrm/ajax/rest...` Or share a screenshot of the console output/Log file

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Joe for the comment. In the search settings, all of the checkboxes for "Autocomplete Contact Search" were checked. We disabled all but "Contact" (which is set by default) and "Email" and now it's working.

Comment: Cool, you're welcome. Also - check out the Optimized Autocomplete extension if you don't already use it - see https://civicrm.org/extensions/optimized-autocomplete